# Download Button not Available for some System Images while Creating AVD | Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, avd-manager

I am using Linux Mint latest Version.

I was trying to Create a New AVD in Android Studio and selected pixel 2 XL as the device.
On the next screen where we have to choose the Sytsem Image some of the System Images aren't showing the "Download Button".

While in Windows 10 it shows the Download Button with the same Options.

I am Dual Booting Windows and Linux Mint.

This issue is occurring on Linux Mint and not present on Windows 10.

The image is attached for the reference here.[image]

I tried the same on WIndows 10, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed after updating Android Studio.